# Beep program not able to open any device

Tags: audio, speakers, system-sounds, beep-code

I am running Debian Stable Linux which is otherwise working very well. I have installed `beep` package with command `apt install beep`. There were no errors. However, the command `beep` is not  working. Following are the errors:

```
$ beep
beep: Error: Could not open any device


$ BEEP_LOG_LEVEL=999 beep
beep-log: Verbose: log_constructor
beep-log: Verbose: beep_driver_console_constructor
beep-log: Verbose: beep_drivers_register 0x564bb79ad6a0 (console)
beep-log: Verbose: beep_driver_evdev_constructor
beep-log: Verbose: beep_drivers_register 0x564bb79ad700 (evdev)
beep: Verbose: evdev driver_detect 0x564bb79ad700 (nil)
beep: Verbose: b-lib: could not stat(2) /dev/input/by-path/platform-pcspkr-event-spkr: No such file or directory
beep: Verbose: console driver_detect 0x564bb79ad6a0 (nil)
beep: Verbose: b-lib: could not open(2) /dev/tty0: Permission denied
beep: Verbose: b-lib: could not stat(2) /dev/vc/0: No such file or directory
beep: Error: Could not open any device
```

There are a number of pages on the net discussing this issue, though mostly are for Ubuntu. However, their  solutions, including `sudo modprobe pcspkr` and `sudo usermod -aG input iuser` did not correct the error.

Where is the problem and how can it be solved?

Comment: Are you sure there is a PC speaker connected to your motherboard?

Comment: How do I check this? Will I need to open the desktop or is there a bash command to find out?

Comment: The command is `beep`. :) Does your computer beep when you power it on? The user manual of the motherboard probably mentions the PC speaker (or pins to connect one), *if it's there*.

Comment: There is no beep on power on. Attached external speakers are there using which I play media files with `vlc` program.

Comment: These are connected to your sound card. [PC speaker is different](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PC_speaker). If there is no PC speaker, see this answer: [*Is there a way to switch the output sound of the beep program to the normal loud speaker instead of beeper?*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/585320/108618)